# Where can I find the full list of winners of the Spirit of Delphi Award?

Tags: delphi

Where can you find the full list of winners of the Spirit of Delphi Award?

I found [this](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/spirit.html), but it is not complete.

- 1998: Robert M. Czerwinski (The Delphi Super Page) and Fedor Koshevnikov, Serge Korolev and Igor Pavluk (RX Library)
- 1999: Marco Cantù and Bob Swart
- 2000: Maxim Peresada (Torry’s Delphi Pages)
- 2001: Project JEDI (a collective award)
- 2002: Mark Miller (of CodeRush fame)
- 2003: Ray Konopka (Raize Software)
- 2004: Nick Hodges (Lemanix then – now – oh, well…)
- 2005: Pierre le Riche (FastMM4)
- 2006: The community
- 2007: Andreas Hausladen

Comment: Excellent programming related question with a definitive answer!

Comment: Maybe the gap's because the Spirit of Delphi was dead for '05 and '06? :P

Comment: IIRC it should be
2005: Pierre le Riche
2006: The community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to this question on StackOverflow, it seems a list has been added at:

http://wings-of-wind.com/2009/10/13/spirit-of-delphi-award-2009/

That post also requests recommendations for 2009's winner, so go down there and add your suggestion.

---

In 2000, [Bob Swart wrote](http://www.drbob42.com/events/2000.htm) that

> "BorCon 2000 ... started with Ben Riga calling the names of all previous winners of the Spirit of Delphi Award (of which Marco Cantù and Bob Swart were the only ones present at BorCon in San Diego)."

---

But this appears to be the first reference to the award:
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10191

And you can find the original voting page at:
http://web.archive.org/web/20000816050908/http://www.borland.com/delphi/vote/

It seems to indicate that the list you have compiled is complete in the early years.

Answer (score 2):

Was there one before 1998?

I don't know that there were any in 05 and 06. I think 2006 was Pierre le Riche of FastMM (if not, then he should have won!)  I am pretty sure there have not been any since 2007 either.

Comment: Pierre LeRiche definitely won it one year.

Comment: The cited link from Marco Cantu has nominations for 2005; le Riche is on the list.

Comment: I think Pierre LeRiche won in 2005.  Maybe we should ask him!